# Why does Format produce this warning as a side-effect?

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to

```
Format[event[][digit[n_], pos[j_]]] ^:= Column[{n, Row[{"[", j, "]"}]}, Alignment -> Center]
```

which seems to work; evaluating `event[][digit[n], pos[1]]` produces [image] as expected.

However, evaluating `?event` produces a warning: `FormatType: Value of option FormatType -> FormatType is not valid`.

Is this an indication that I've done something wrong with `Format`, is it an irrelevant side-effect or is it a bug?

(I'm using 12.3)

Comment: It looks like this message is new in M12, and I think it could be considered a bug. At any rate, you can avoid the message if you also specify StandardForm, e.g., `Format[event[][digit[n_], pos[j_]], StandardForm] := ...`. The use of `^:=` instead of just `:=` is unnecessary.

Comment: `UpSetDelayed` is irrelevant in this particular case or in general with `Format`?

Comment: In general with `Format`. For example, see what happens when you try `Format /: Format[x, InputForm] := 1`

Comment: I apologize but I don't understand what kind of a counterexample this is; isn't using `TagSetDelayed` like that equivalent to trying to assign an `UpValue` to `Format`? why would you want to do something like that, this way?

Comment: Notice that the message you get is `Rule for Format of x can only be attached to x.` In other words, using SetDelayed for Format by default is treated as `UpSetDelayed`. It never creates a `FormatValues` for Format.